# Text in the dom get selected when click the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added some text element in the Window, while selecting the screen the text in the DOM get selected as below

[image]

i have mentioned  "pointer-events": "all", for text element, but his not working. Can anyone suggest some way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in document.ready

```
$('html').on("dragstart, selectstart",function(a){
this.stopPropagation()
this.find("*").andSelf().attr("unselectable","on");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user-select: none` (with the usual vendor prefixes) to stop the text from being able to selected at all.

Or, you can capture the click even in JavaScript and `preventDefault()`. This may work better - it seems you only want to stop clicking from selecting. The former would make the text always impossible to select.